# CentOS 6.5 kernel vs CentOS 7 kernel

Tags: centos

Its been long that i have heard that CentOS 6.5 kernel (2009) is "Too Old" as compared to CentOS 7 kernel (2013).

I want to better understand what is meant by "Too Old". Comparing 2.6.32 to 3.10, what are the things i will not be able to do on 2.6 as compared to 3.10?

Any answer here would be valuable. Thanks!

Comment: One of biggest improvements would be the introduction of cgroups. They offer a much better mechanism for limiting and controlling processes.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is too broad to be answered completely here, but I will answer with a truncated list in terms of 'major' changes taken form the [CentOS wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS7#head-b02657cf2e223edb2d7946cbc45086d42c2bb41b):

> As with every first major Release most of the packages have changed
>   and have been updated to more recent versions. It would exceed the
>   scope of this document to list them all. Most notable changes are:
>
> ```
> Kernel updated to 3.10.0
> Support for Linux Containers
> Open VMware Tools and 3D graphics drivers out of the box
> OpenJDK-7 as default JDK
> In Place Upgrade from 6.5 to 7.0 (as already mentioned)
> LVM-snapshots with ext4 and XFS
> Switch to systemd, firewalld and GRUB2
> XFS as default file system
> iSCSI and FCoE in kernel space
> Support for PTPv2
> Support for 40G Ethernet Cards
> Supports installations in UEFI Secure Boot mode on compatible hardware
> ```

For more in-depth information on changes I would suggest reading over the [RHEL 7.0 Release notes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.0_Release_Notes/part-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7.0_Release_Notes-New_Features.html).